# Storing login credentials for iPhone app on server database

Tags: iphone, sql, database

I am building an app, and would like to store users' login credentials on some sort of database on a server. I am thinking this should be a SQL server, but I don't know what's best. Do you know of any great tutorials to get me started?

Comment: Well this is not a new thing. After all almost every iphone app uses some kind of interaction with the server. So, if you are an iphone app developer then it should be your major concern to how to connect to the server through iphone and send credential, you could find some good web programmers already otherwise if you go to learn web programming from the beginning, it will take you 2/3 months to learn to implements a good and a secure api.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you'll likely need an SSL certificate (if you're unfamiliar with the term, it very basically allows a secure, encrypted connection to the site (ie. https://), so people sniffing the WiFi network can't steal user passwords), which will add some cost to a webserver if you don't already have one.

Comment: To clarify, all the apps I've worked on thus far have been games and such, which have required no internet connectivity whatsoever. But thanks to both of you for the help!